# Declaring 3 sets in GLPK->syntax error in literal set

Tags: set, glpk, mathprog

I have this small code:

```
 param n, integer, > 0; # number of clients
param m, integer, > 0; # number of facilities
param g, integer, > 0;

set I := 1..n;
set J := 1..m;
set G := 1..g;

param d{i in I, j in J};/* distance for client i to factory j*/
param w{i in I, j in J};/* distance for client i to factory j*/
param l{j in J}; # distance from factory j to factory 1
param F{j in J}; # cost of open a factory in J
param s{i in I, g in G};
```

The problem is on the s, it always says drdrd.mod:13: syntax error in literal set , if I change the g in G for j in J, everything is ok. Is not possible to have 3 differents sets?

And another question I could not solve, if I put instead of i in I, 2 in I (because  I want to take into account the first 2 numbers ) it says also the same error message.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

`g` is defined as a parameter in

```
param g, integer, > 0;
```

so you can't use it as an index name in

```
param s{i in I, g in G};
```

To fix this rename the index (or parameter):

```
param s{i in I, gg in G};
```